# Python: List comprehension with list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

How would I write the following code in list comprehension?

```py
with open('some_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in lines]
list_of_lists = [[int(elm) for elm in line.split(' ')] for line in lines]
```

---

My file looks something like this:

```
3 8 6 9 4
4 3 0 8 6
2 8 3 6 9
3 7 9 0 3
```

Which means that:

```
grid = '3 8 6 9 4\n4 3 0 8 6\n2 8 3 6 9\n3 7 9 0 3'
```

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. Not that it's necessary, but I was trying to get a better understanding of list comprehension. @SpghttCd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a try , first split each lines and you will get a list of numbers as string, so `map` function can be used to change it to `int`:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    k = [list(map(int,i.split())) for i in f.readlines()]
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to apply `str.strip` and `str.split` separately. Instead, combine them in one operation. The list comprehension is constructed by defining a list element followed by an iteration over a `for` loop.

Also note that `str.strip` without an argument will deal with `\n` as well as whitespace. Similarly, `str.split` without an argument will split by whitespace.

```
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""3 8 6 9 4
4 3 0 8 6
2 8 3 6 9
3 7 9 0 3""")

# replace x with open('some_file.txt', 'r')
with x as grid:
    list_of_lists = [[int(elm) for elm in line.strip().split()] for line in grid]
```

Result:

```
print(list_of_lists)

[[3, 8, 6, 9, 4],
 [4, 3, 0, 8, 6],
 [2, 8, 3, 6, 9],
 [3, 7, 9, 0, 3]]
```

With built-ins, it's marginally more efficient to use `map`:

```
list_of_lists = [list(map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in grid]
```

Answer (score 1):

`int` does not care about newline characters, so you can skip stripping those.

```
>>> fake_file = '3 8 6 9 4\n4 3 0 8 6\n2 8 3 6 9\n3 7 9 0 3\n'.splitlines()
>>> [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in fake_file]
[[3, 8, 6, 9, 4], [4, 3, 0, 8, 6], [2, 8, 3, 6, 9], [3, 7, 9, 0, 3]]
```

Note that `pandas` and `numpy` offer high level functions for reading in data such as this, e.g. `numpy.loadtxt` or `pandas.read_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function

```
grid = open('some.txt', 'r')
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in grid]

list_of_lists = []

f = lambda line: [int(elm) for elm in line.split(' ')]
list_of_lists = map(f, lines)
print(list_of_lists)
```

Or You could implement it even shorter

```
f = lambda line: map(int, line.split(' '))
list_of_lists = map(f, lines)
print(list_of_lists)
```